# What's wrong with this stored procedure inserting data?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that inserts into a database table, but it will not run. The debugger says that there is incorrect syntax near '(' but I swear that the code is correct...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help oh mighty stackoverflow hive mind!

The stored proc is below:

```
Create Proc InsertStaffMember
 (@fname varchar(50), 
  @lname varchar(50), 
  @initials varchar(3), 
  @phone varchar(20), 
  @phoneext varchar(10), 
  @stafftype char(1))
AS
    Insert into 
    (t09FirstName, t09LastName, t09Int, t09Phone, t09PhoneExt, t09Type)
    Values
    (@fname, @lname, @initials, @phone, @phoneext, @stafftype)
GO
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't specify a table name in your INSERT.

Comment: Yeah Jamiec this is such a noob mistake my face is red just looking at it